# Can I print #defines given their values in C?

Tags: c

I have

```
#define ADD 5
#define SUB 6
```

Can I print ADD and SUB given their values 5 and 6?

Comment: do you mean that you want to output both name and value in your program?

Comment: Can you clarify the question a little ?

Comment: I have 5 and 6.. Can I print "ADD" and "SUB" with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

The names of the `define`d symbols are removed by the preprocessor, so the compiler never sees them.

If these names are important at runtime, they need to be encoded in something more persistent than just preprocessor symbol names. Perhaps a table with strings and integers:

```
#define DEFINE_OP(n) { #n, n }

static const struct {
  const char *name;
  int        value;
} operators[] = {
  DEFINE_OP(ADD),
  DEFINE_OP(SUB),
};
```

This uses the stringifying preprocessor operator `#` to avoid repetitions.

With the above, you can trivially write look-up code:

```
const char * op_to_name(int op)
{
  size_t i;

  for(i = 0; i < sizeof operators / sizeof *operators; ++i)
    if(operators[i].value == op)
      return operators[i].name;
  return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like

```
printf("%d", ADD);
```

and it will print 5

The thing you have to remember about defines is:
Defines are substituted into the source code by the preprocessor before it is compiled so all instances of ADD in your code are substituted by 5. After the preprocessor the printf looks like this:

```
printf("%d", 5);
```

So to answer your question:
No you can't do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not in via some reverse lookup mechanism wherein the value `5` is somehow symbolic in regards to the string `"ADD"`.  The symbols defined via a `#define` are tectually replaced by the pre-processor.  You can however keep it simple:

```
const char *get_name(int value) {
    switch(value) {
    case ADD:
        return "ADD";
    case SUB:
        return "SUB";
    default:
        return "WHATEVER";
    }
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%s = %d\n", get_name(ADD), ADD);
    printf("%s = %d", get_name(SUB), SUB);
}
```

Comment: Please don't delete your comments before I have time to reply to them.

Comment: @Minion91: Why not?  I obviously rethought what I said and decided to remove it?  There's nothing to respond to.  And I didn't change my mind, just saw no reason to bring it up.  Saying that this cannot be done is just silly.  It can trivially be done.

Comment: Because i don't like it when people down-vote me without a reason.

Comment: @Minion91: Ok, here's the reason; you didn't answer the question.  You said this "cannot be done", which is insanely ridiculous.  Of course it can, trivially.  If you think a switch statement is "bad practice" please enlighten me.  This is obviously a beginner, what overly-complex solution would you suggest?

Comment: I said it can't be done like that, which is 100% correct, as the ADD isn't even in the source anymore.

Comment: I suggest learning beginners good practices and keeping them away from the preprocessor as it is an overly-complex thing. I find it hard to give an alternative because his reasoning for this is unclear, but imho he should probably try a different approach than the macros.

Comment: @Minion91: Then by all means, suggest such an approach.  That is my only real problem with your response; it lacks a solution, and lies about the non-existence of one.  And please, show me one serious C project which doesn't use the pre-processor.  I'll be waiting.  I mean, it's one thing to *abuse* the pre-processor, but "keep [beginners] away [from it]" and claim that it is "overly complex" is just silly.

Comment: My point is there is no clean solution to this problem and it shouldn't be solved by kludging a workaround but by restructuring the program to incorporate this functionality.

Comment: @Minion91:... and they would do so... how exactly?  Why do you refuse to offer an actual solution?  All I hear is a lot of religious sounding preaching about "best practiced" and the evil pre-processor, yet no actual solutions to the problem,not even an allusion to one.

Comment: @Minion91: You should solve simple problems in as simple a way as possible and practical.  There is absolutely nothing wrong with a switch statement or lookup table for this task. If, at a later time, the requirements change, or you see that it is becoming a maintenance headache, then you can change it.  Until that day comes you're wasting your time on what should be a 30 second task.

Comment: Because, like i said, multiple times, I can't give a solution without more context. This is not a simple task, this is problem with the authors line of thinking. He shouldn't have arrived at this question because there should be better ways to preform the task he wants to preform. Also: I would not like to manage your code

Comment: @Minion91: You have no idea what kind of code I write, no need to flatter yourself.  It is a simple task, and since we're going all ad hominem here, this whole discussion makes me question your ability to get much of anything done.

Comment: I have enough of this conversation, I made my point, if you are having trouble with it, good for you!

Comment: @Minion91: I don't think you  made much of a point at all, but... I did just realize I add `case 5` instead of `case ADD` up there (not sure why). I wouldn't like that much either.

Comment: Okay one more time: here is my point, specially for you, clear and simple: Teach new programmers good practices, don't let them keep their bad. But you will obviously disagree

Comment: @Minion91: I would once again love to hear what is "bad" about this and how you would do it better.  It's easy to go around saying "this is bad" and "that is bad", but if you don't offer a solution then you're just wasting people's time.  If this were me I would go with an approach similar to what unwind described (which, Ghast! uses the pre-processor).  However, for such a simple question I decided to give the most simple answer possible.

Answer (score 0):

With modern C, since C99, this is even much simpler than unwind's answer by using designated initializers and compound literals

```
#define DEFINE_OP(n) [n] = #n

#define OPNAMES ((char const*const opNames[]){  \
  DEFINE_OPT(ADD),                              \
  DEFINE_OPT(SUB),                              \
  })

inline
char const* getOp(unsigned op) {
  size_t const maxOp = sizeof OPNAMES/ sizeof *OPNAMES;
  if (op >= maxOp || !OPNAMES[op]) return "<unknown operator>";
  else return OPNAMES[op];
}
```

Any modern compiler should be able then to expand calls as `getOp(ADD)` at compile time.